# The application does not switch the tracks in background iOS (AVPlayer)

Tags: ios, avplayer

There is an audio player is permitted to play in the background, in the background everything is fine playing, but the next track switches only if the app is active

Here's an example, first you start the track, then turn the app (in the debugger changes the time of the track to 0, so he switched to the next)
In checking reason at a standstill until I open the app after changing everything is fine

(visible in the video a piece of code that stops execution until you open the app)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1RgvL4hf_A

What to pay attention?
I would be grateful if at least hint what the problem is